# Can we access connection object in multiple activities in android?

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2005

I have created a program in which i have **Created connection with SQL Server**. Now **I want to access that object in another activity for the next query** can I do that.

If yes then please tell me HOW?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
  void connectionToSql()
  {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        url ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.15;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName="+DBName+";integratedSecurity=true;user="+UserName+";password="+Password;

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Just a function for driverManager.getConnection.. nothing else
                asdf();
            }
        }, 10000);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void asdf()
{
  try {
    conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  selectitem();
}

void selectitem()
{
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lalit_db;");

        while(resultSet.next()){
            Log.w(s2, resultSet.getString(3));
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("It is the error", "............");
    }

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b1.setBackgroundColor(c.TRANSPARENT);
                b1.setTextColor(c.RED);

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,menus.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
}
```

And now I want to access that object `conn` of Connection `in another activity` menus.java.

This is my **menus.java**

```
public class menus extends Activity{

ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

Connection xyz;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_category);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.menulist);

  ////////////////Here i am trying to copy the object of conn in new object xyz
    xyz = MainActivity.conn;

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "In Menus.......", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String[] values = new String[]{"Adroid Developer",".Net Developer","Java Developer","BA"};

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

         list.setAdapter(adapter); 
                      getValues();
}

void getValues()
{
    try {
        st = xyz.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT name from lalit_db where category='.Net'");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            Log.w("Here is the result..", rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}       
}
```

But it gives error as :

```
01-02 12:49:31.489: W/dalvikvm(9917): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.z/com.example.z.menus}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-02 12:49:31.558: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Is 'conn' defined as static in MainActivity? If not, try that.

Comment: I did that changes and it works too but when I am going to execute a query again it gives error Please have a look at the answer(Down) given by CoolMonster @NigelK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make conn as static variable in MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity
{
static object conn;

}
```

just accessing the object will return null. static object alone live throughout the life-cycle of application.

Edit As requested:

```
private class MyNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected Boolean doInBackground()  {

        try {
        st = xyz.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT name from lalit_db where category='.Net'");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            Log.w("Here is the result..", rs.getString(1));
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
return false;
    }
return true;
}

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          Log.w(“Process completed”);
     }
 }
```

new MyNetworkTask().execute();

Comment: You said `static object conn;` but it is the object of Connection class. How can we do such a change? @CoolMonster

Comment: its just for example replace the object with actual Object type.

Comment: Yes, I think it takes that object in next activity. Thank you. BUT, when i am trying to execute another query it gives error.

`01-03 05:25:12.685: W/dalvikvm(1234): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-03 05:25:12.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 05:25:12.806: E/AndroidRuntime(1234): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.z/com.example.z.menus}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` @CoolMonster

Comment: U never perform any network related task in main-thread. either run it new thread or use AsynTask.

 Also there is a way override this policy but its not good approach.

Comment: ok sir, I would like to know how to do AsynTask. Can you give any link or a short example or else please. @CoolMonster

Comment: **For the next query** I have **carried object of Connection is it right?** or i should carry object of **Statement**. As i know statement should be created again but connection is one time activity. Right?? @CoolMonster

Comment: You can create the statement as when needed. there is no need of keep the statement object alive.For asyntask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Sir i am trying to do that with `AsyncTask` but its too hard for me because i dont know anything about it. Can you tell me what are the parameters ? 

**Will you please modify my given code and answer me using the `AsyncTask` sir.** @CoolMonster

Comment: U can create a AsyncTask without paramters also, check the edited answer. Also check forum for this kind of examples.

Comment: Sir I have done what you told me It goes to AsyncTask but when i am trying to do  `xyz.createStatement()` it gives the same error. And as you have done `protected boolean doInBackground()` in your answer, but the it tell me to create `protected Void doInBackground()` so i created but still it is not working.


**Basically tell me where should i put your answer in MainActivity.java or in menus.java as my question?**

Thanks for your all type of valuable help @CoolMonster